# Provision App Service Environment with Terraform

Tags: terraform, azure-app-service-envrmnt, terraform-provider-azure

Is it possible to deploy an Azure App Service Environment with Terraform?  I can seem to find a provider specifically for that so was not sure if it could be accomplished with the azurerm_app_service resource.

Comment: This may be some help to you https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/712

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be working for me with using [azurerm_template_deployment](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/template_deployment.html) as a **workaround**, which uses ARM template inside Terraform. It does take a long time thought (47 min in my case) but it seems to work. I used it like this:

```
resource "azurerm_template_deployment" "test" {
  name                = "mytemplate001"
  resource_group_name = "my-test-rg"

  template_body = <<DEPLOY
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "appServicePoolName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[concat('sp', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]"
    },
    "appServiceEnvironmentName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "myenv-test"
    }
  },
  "resources": [
{
      "name": "[parameters('appServicePoolName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
      "location": "West Europe",
      "apiVersion": "2017-08-01",
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "My-Service-Pool"
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "[parameters('appServicePoolName')]",
        "hostingEnvironment": "[parameters('appServiceEnvironmentName')]",
        "hostingEnvironmentId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments', parameters('appServiceEnvironmentName'))]"
      },
      "sku": {
        "name": "I1",
        "tier": "Isolated",
        "size": "I1",
        "family": "I"
      }
}
  ]
}
DEPLOY

  # these key-value pairs are passed into the ARM Template's `parameters` block
  parameters {
    "appServicePoolName"        = "my-test-asp"
    "appServiceEnvironmentName" = "myenv-test"
  }

  deployment_mode = "Incremental"
}
```

there seems to be a [problem with Azure Rest API](https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/issues/4915) that is preventing Terraform from using it properly. So, hopefully it will be fixed soon and we will be able to use App Service Environment natively in Terraform.

Answer (score 0):

There has been work done by "the team" in this area.

https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/pull/869

However, if you read the posts there, you'll find that there is currently an issue with the   "Azure API (rather than the SDK)" (quote from article) .... (not fault of terraform team), so this "task" is in limbo currently.

Quote from article

> "but we can't proceed with this until that's fixed, unfortunately."

Comment: is there any progress on this? I am having the same [Status=400 Code="BadRequest" Message="NumberOfWorkers is invalid."] error as here https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/pull/850
Is there a workaround for this?